# Flutter "create" command - anyway to specify the bundle ID and the signing & capabilities team when creating project itself?

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter so maybe I am doing something wrong or missing something.

I am using MacOS.

Whenever I have to start a new Flutter project, I launch terminal and type:

```
flutter create my_project_name
```

Once done, I have open the `my_project_name/iOS/Runner.xcworkspace` in Xcode and manually change the `bundle ID` as well as set the `Signing & Capabilitie` team to my Apple Developer account name.

Is there a way to skip the extra steps? Aka is there a way to specify the `bundle ID` and the `Signing & Capabilitie` team in terminal itself when creating the flutter project?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the org name and project name like this

```
flutter create --org com.somename yourapp
```

this will result in bundle id `com.somename.yourapp` For more you can check `flutter create -h` It will display all possible parameters. Not sure if you can set the developer identity.

Comment: note to beginners (like me), the space in @Kaushik is required. first time i tried flutter create --org com.companyname.appname and got error, but flutter create --org com.companyname appname works just as it should